# How do I avoid nested Monads in fp-ts or deal with them elegantly?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads, fp-ts

I have a sequence of code which needs to go through the below steps (pseudo code):

```
  jobsRepository.findById // <-- this returns a TaskEither
  jobs.openJob // <-- jobs.openJob returns an Either
  jobsRepository.update // <-- this returns another TaskEither
  createJobOpenedEvent // simple function that returns an IJobOpenedEvent
                       // given an IOpenJob
```

If I map/chain those steps together I end up with a type like `TaskEither<IError, Either<IError, TaskEither<IError, IOpenJob>>>` which is obviously a bit awkward.

My current solution to flatten all of this into a simple `TaskEither<IError, IJobOpenedEvent>` type looks like the following (real code):

```
import { flatten } from "fp-ts/lib/Chain";
import { Either, either, left, right } from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import {
  fromEither,
  TaskEither,
  taskEither,
  tryCatch,
} from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";

const createJobOpenedEvent = (openJob: jobs.IOpenJob): IJobOpenedEvent => ({
  name: "jobOpened",
  payload: openJob,
});

export const openJobHandler = (
  command: IOpenJobCommand
): TaskEither<IError, IJobOpenedEvent> =>
  flatten(taskEither)(
    flatten(taskEither)(
      jobsRepository
        .findById(command.jobId) // <-- this returns a TaskEither<IError, IJob>
        .map(jobs.openJob) // <-- jobs.openJob returns an Either<IError, IOpenJob>
        .map(fromEither)
        .map(jobsRepository.update) // <-- this returns a TaskEither<IError,IOpenJob>
    )
  ).map(createJobOpenedEvent);
```

My question is - is there a better way to handle this nesting? I feel like I am doing this wrong as I am new to functional programming and don't understand all the theory. Having all the nested `flatten(taskEither)` calls and converting an `Either` into a `TaskEither` with `fromEither` seems bad to me.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use `flatMap`/`chain` instead of nesting lots of `map`s in lots of `flatten`s

Comment: `fromEither` is fine (unless there's a specific helper method a la `mapEither` on `TaskEither`)

Comment: Ah wow yes you're right, using `chain` works great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Bergi for his comment I was able to find the following solution using `chain` instead of `map`:

```
export const openJobHandler = (
  command: IOpenJobCommand
): TaskEither<IError, IJobOpenedEvent> =>
  jobsRepository
    .findById(command.jobId)
    .map(jobs.openJob)
    .chain(fromEither)
    .chain(jobsRepository.update)
    .map(createJobOpenedEvent)
```

Comment: Hi, what is the difference between `chain` and `flatmap`?

Comment: Hi Cristian, they are two names for the same thing :)